# Unable to access my encrypted internal hard drive with Win 7 on it

Tags: mount

I'm quite new to Ubuntu and I've tried all the post related to my issue but couldn't solve it. I'll try to give as much information as possible.

I'm using 12.04 LTS on an external hard disk and boot my machine with Ubuntu. The external Hard disk on which Ubuntu is installed is partitioned into two: P5 and P6. P5 is the one where Ubuntu is installed and P6 is for storage purpose.

When I logon to Ubuntu, I'm not able to mount my internal hard disk. If I use `sudo fdisk -l`, I can see the internal drive there but when I try to mount it, it gives me `NTFS Signature is missing`. Here are the results of the two cmds:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xeef597d0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   625139711   312568832    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x389ea96f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              63   106710400    53355169    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       106711040   488392703   190840832    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


$ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /media/external
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Here I'd like to inform that my internal hard disk is encrypted and is protected with a pwd. When I normally bootup my machine, it first asks me to enter the HDD pwd and then the encryption pwd and then it logs me into Win 7.

I think that it's because of the HDD pwd and encryption that I'm not able to mount my internal drive to Ubuntu but not sure.

Is there a way that I can mount my internal drive onto Ubuntu without removing the HDD pwd or encryption on my internal drive?

Comment: What encryption software was used to encrypt the disk?, Truecrypt, BitLocker etc...

Comment: when I use Gparted I see the internal drive but the filesystem for /dev/sda1 is shown as "unknown".

Comment: symantec pgp desktop is the one that is used for encryption.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't out of the box support this kind of Encryption.  You can install some software from Symantec that should be able to mount the drive altough I cannot confirm this there is a article regarding this below.  It looks like you need to be able to login and download the software.

http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH198150